# Unfortunately, appname has stopped when i trying to send 2 data or more by bundle

Tags: android

I'm trying to send 3 data from one activity to another activity
But when I try to use it in my app , it doesn't work , and "Unfortunately , appname has stopped" shows
Here is my code

```
// 3 data are 3 index of 3 string array 
// position === I'm using list view and it's position of list view's item
String data [] = { dataSeprateTitle[position], dataSeprateSender[position], dataSepratePessage[position]}; 
Intent r = New Intent(getapplicationContext(), readBook.class);
r.putextra ("KEYBOOK", data);
StartActivity(r);
```

And here is my second class ...

```
Bundle get = getIntent().getExtras();
String [] textbook = null;
if ( get != null) {
    textbook = get.getStringArray("KEYBOOK");
}
```

Excuse me for capital and small characters , I write the codes again and maybe I did not pay attention to that

Comment: Try to use `adb logcat` to obtain the exception trace so that you can see where exactly the error happens. And please correct your code, because as shown here, it wouldn't even compile.

Comment: As said, post the stacktrace that should appear in your logcat. Also note there is a limit of ~1mb of data you can sent in Intents

Answer (score -1):

This code sends array of integer values

Initialize array List

```
List<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Add values to array List

test.add(1);
test.add(2);
test.add(3);
Intent intent=new Intent(this, targetActivty.class);
```

Send the array list values to target activity

```
    intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("test", (ArrayList<Integer>) test);

startActivity(intent);
here you get values on targetActivty

Intent intent=getIntent();
ArrayList<String> test = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("test");
```

Hope it help

Comment: `Hope it help`. No it does not. Posting random code that covers the same subject is not equivalent of answering OP question.

Comment: Thanks ... I try it but again the same error shows , and I have to force stop the app :(